# Generic pressed state for buttons

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to achieve similar effect to pressed Google play images or iOS image buttons (sorry bad images positioning):

[image: 1] [image: 2]

So basically I have image and I want to show greyed transparent overlay on top on press state.

Since I have many of this button I would like to have some generic solution that I can apply for all `imageView`/`Button` and do not duplicate xml drawables.

I was looking for answers on SO, also searched Google. My understanding I should create custom drawable where I will for pressed state mix image and grey overlay. But I Android xml understanding is not enough yet. Could anyone point for something similar?

Comment: I think this is ios way and Android native is described here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17145615/using-image-in-a-android-button-with-effects