# OnTouch Apply glow effect to center of image

Tags: android, touch-event, glow

I have a image and I need to apply glow effect to center of the image using OnTouchListener

Something like this.

[image]

How can I achieve this effect? I have looked into examples where we can apply glow effect to outer part of the image.

We can achieve this by using a white image and place on top the background image, but can we do it without using images?

**EDIT**

I found this post as well but no solution.

[Android : Image button or button Highlighted with Effect when Pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16514221)

Comment: have you tried setAlpha??

Comment: @cyberwalker No i havent tried with that,can you please help me with that

Comment: Here is link that will help you, 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6281783/dynamically-generated-line-with-glow-effective

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the `setOnTouchListener` get the `getDrawingCache()` of the image, Create a gradient bitmap of what you want and then overlay the images on top of one another

Try this

```
final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    imageView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if(drawIt){
                    drawIt = false;
                    //Build the cache
                    imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                    Bitmap original = imageView.getDrawingCache();
                    //Build the gradient
                    Bitmap gradient = getGradient();
                    //Overlay the images
                    Bitmap finalImage = overlay(original,gradient,event.getX(),event.getY());
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(finalImage);
                }
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                drawIt = true;
                break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

private Bitmap getGradient() {
    RadialGradient gradient = new RadialGradient(200 , 200, 200, 0xFFFFFFFF,
            0x00000000, android.graphics.Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
    Paint p = new Paint();
    p.setDither(true);
    p.setShader(gradient);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(400, 400, Config.ARGB_8888);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bitmap);
    c.drawCircle(200, 200, 200, p);

    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, 50, 50, false);
}

private Bitmap overlay(Bitmap bmp1, Bitmap bmp2,float x, float y) {
    Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp1.getWidth(), bmp1.getHeight(), bmp1.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp1, new Matrix(), null);
    // Use your x and y cordinates here
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, 100,100, null);
    return bmOverlay;
}
```

Here is what I got

[image]

You can do your modifications here i have [uploaded](http://www.mediafire.com/?pbg4zzypykkj0bf) the project for you

Best of Luck

***EDIT***

To draw it at center use this line in the `overlay` method

```
 canvas.drawBitmap(bmp2, bmp1.getWidth()/2 - bmp2.getWidth()/2,bmp1.getHeight()/2  - bmp2.getHeight()/2, null);
```

And for adding bitmap to button use this

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),finalImage);
btn.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

But note that when you set this bitmap to button the button will resize so better not use `wrap_content` but specify the height and width in hard code like `25dp` or `100dp` etc. That is the logic which you have to control

You can also use [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) and set it as

```
btn.setImageBitmap(finalImage);
```

**For MotionEvent**

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawIt = true;
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        if(drawIt){
            //Build the cache
            imageView.buildDrawingCache();
            Bitmap original = imageView.getDrawingCache();
            //Build the gradient
            Bitmap gradient = getGradient();
            //Overlay the images
            Bitmap finalImage = overlay(original,gradient,event.getX(),event.getY());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(finalImage);
            Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),finalImage);
            btn.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
            }
        break;

    case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
        drawIt = false;
        break;
}
```

***EDIT 2***

Declare these instance variables

```
private boolean drawIt = true;
Button btn1,btn2;
int x_limit, y_limit;
Bitmap bmpOrignal, bmpGradient, bmpOverlay;
```

and code the `onTouch` like this

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(drawIt){
        drawIt = false;
        v.buildDrawingCache();
        bmpOrignal = v.getDrawingCache();
        bmpGradient = getGradient();
        bmpOverlay = overlay(bmpOrignal,bmpGradient);
        x_limit = v.getLeft() + bmpOrignal.getWidth();
        y_limit = v.getTop() + bmpOrignal.getHeight();

    }
    if(event.getX() > x_limit || event.getY() > y_limit){
        ((Button)v).setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmpOrignal));
    }else {
        ((Button)v).setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),bmpOverlay));
    }

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
        drawIt = true ;
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can download the new updated project from [here](http://www.mediafire.com/download/6n8rx4d12v13rrz/new_ImageViewTesting.zip)

Comment: Thanks for your time, i needed this effect, i tried to modify you code but its not working for me, i need the white bitmap to be draw exactly to center of the black image and i am trying for some effect like onTouch cancel the white bitmap should be gone,if you can helpme with these it would be great,

Comment: one more thing , can i use this effect for Buttons? i guess its only for image view

Comment: thanks,now its coming in center, regarding the onTouch cancel effect ? can you help me , i tried a lot but i am not able to do that

Comment: @Goofy : Whats your onTouch cancel, Explain i detail what you want i'll reply back tomorrow morning. bye

Comment: Now onTouch MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN we are setting the bitmap, if onTouch MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL i need to remove the bitmap, i hope you got my point

Comment: thanks, i have checked it now, its not working,i had tried the same thing

Comment: i feel that once the bitmap is set, we need to remove the bitmap, like make it to null or something

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36829/discussion-between-goofy-and-girish-nair)

Comment: i have one more small problem related to bitmap can you please help me'

Comment: hey, i tried this with image view and its not applying , i am not getting why so, can you please have a look at it once

Answer (score 3):

How about drawing a circle using

```
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp);
canvas.drawCircle(x, y, radius, paint);
```

Then drawing the same circle over and over again at a slightly lesser alpha and bigger radius in a for loop?

```
Paint.setAlpha();
```

Edit: Actually that sounds pretty bad for the memory but heck haven't tried it before.